# How should we direct people here from forum.civicrm.org?

Tags: discussion

I have put up a notice on forum.civicrm.org saying

> **Have a question about CiviCRM? Get it answered quickly at our new Stack Exchange Q+A site**
>   This forum is being deprecated for all questions and should only be used for discussions, bug reporting, etc.

Can you suggest something better? We can then replace it with the most popular answer? Feel free to include formatting, etc.

This is related to [CiviCRM StackExchange vs. CiviCRM forum](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/civicrm-stackexchange-vs-civicrm-forum) and deciding what parts of the forum to keep. I think a nicely crafted notice will help us on our way...

Answer (score 1):

I edited it slightly to read

> **Have a question about CiviCRM? Get it answered quickly at the new Stack Exchange Q+A site**
>
> This forum is being deprecated for all questions and is now only for discussions, beta-testing, bug reporting, etc. [Learn more](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36280.0.html).

and created [this page](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36280.0.html) on the forum to spell out the differences.

Answer (score 0):

And I have edited Coleman's [new page](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36280.0.html) to add "feature requests".  See why [here](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/is-there-a-document-defining-the-scope-of-this-site).