# Is there a document defining the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, support

Earlier today moderator Robert Cartaino [edited a post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/345/revisions), commenting that

> Feature requests for CiviCRM are off topic here.

I happen to agree with him, but my question is (especially since he is not a CiviCRM user) *how did he know that?* Is there a document somewhere that spells out what is on and off topic for this site? If so, shouldn't it be prominently displayed to newcomers? If not, how does anyone know what is on or off topic? Is it simply by following the example of other posts?

Should we be compiling articles of definition?

Comment: @RobertCartaino hoping you can shed light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Help > Tour links to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour and that seems to be where what is on and off topic is defined.

That page seems to exist on all sites and appears to be a standard template that is customised for each particular SE site.

The first section clearly states

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum.
>   There's no chit-chat.

Then in **Get answers to practical, detailed questions** there is a "do ask" list and a "don't ask" list.

We should add **Feature requests** to the "Don't ask" list,

A feature request is outside the Q and A format. It is likely to promote discussion and therefore would be off-topic on any SE site.

Feature requests should remain on the forum.

I don't know who can edit that page now.  On an established site I imagine it is the moderators, but we don't seem to have any CiviCRM moderators  - perhaps you only get them once the site is out of beta.

I also think that questions about bugs such as [Why does a 100% discount not work?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/379/100-discount-did-not-work) are off topic for this site and should remain on the forum.

Answer (score 1):

The [tour page](http://CiviCRM.stackexchange.com) gives you a quick-start about how the site works, but the '[help center](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help)' is where you'll actually find the primary source for what is on topic for this subject — [What topics can I ask about here?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your moderators will be able to edit that page once they are appointed as your scope takes hold.

Regarding how I knew that feature requests were off topic here, that is a philosophical distinction that applies network wide:

We get a lot of requests from project teams about how they can use Stack Exchange to support their communities; the result is sometimes a site like this one. Stack Exchange works really well for *technical* support questions, as long as the project teams are not trying to outsource their entire customer support channel to Stack Exchange. Questions about billing issues, bug reports, future roadmap discussions, and feature requests are best handled by the internal team, so we typically recommend a team host such discussions on their own site. It's a customer support issue, and not really well-suited to this type of Q&A.